# How to develop custom modules for Odoo.sh with private repositories

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo.sh

I have developed a custom module for Odoo.sh and plan to develop more. I would like each module to have its own (private) Github repository so I am trying to add the module to my Odoo.sh project as a submodule as described [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/administration/odoo_sh/advanced/submodules.html?highlight=submodule). I am able to add the  repository to the project as a submodule if I make it public  but I want to use private repos.

The documentation states that private submodules cannot be added from the Odoo.sh interface but can be added using Git on the local machine. So I have followed the instructions to add the submodule to my local project using Git and have pushed the repository with the submodule to Odoo.sh. Then I see the following status in the Odoo.sh Branches page:

[image: Build Error]

There is nothing in the log. I am finding it very difficult to figure out a practical workflow for developing private modules for deployment to Odoo.sh. Any suggestions and/or references would be welcome.

Comment: I've changed the title question, because i think the core of your question is related to private repositories.

Comment: I have the same problem, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set a deploy key for your private repo as described [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/administration/odoo_sh/getting_started/settings.html)

> When a repository is private, it is not possible to publicly download
> its branches and revisions. For that reason, you need to configure a
> deploy key for Odoo.sh, so the remote Git server allows our platform
> to download the revisions of this private repository.
>
> To configure the deploy key for a private repository, proceed as
> follows:
>
> - in the input, paste the SSH URL of your private sub-repository and click on Add,
>
>   - e.g. git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
>   - it can be another Git server than Github, such as Bitbucket, Gitlab or even your own self-hosted server
> - copy the public key,
>
>   - it should look like ssh-rsa some…random…characters…here…==
> - in the settings of the private sub-repository, add the public key amongst the deploy keys.
>
>   - Github.com: Settings ‣ Deploy keys ‣ Add deploy key
>   - Bitbucket.com: Settings ‣ Access keys ‣ Add key
>   - Gitlab.com: Settings ‣ Repository ‣ Deploy Keys
>   - Self-hosted: append the key to the git user’s authorized_keys file in its .ssh directory